# Consuming Messages from Amazon SQS using Spring

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

i am using the Amazon SQS as Message Queue. I am investigating how it is possible to set up a Spring consumer within Tomcat that would consume messages. However i looked around and it seems to say that to deploy a Spring Message Driven Bean to consume messages from Queue in Tomcat, i would need TomcatEE / Tomcat + ActiveMQ.

At the same time i have also reviewed the following SQS-Spring driver and wonder if it is of much use. http://nevado.skyscreamer.org/quickstart.html

Could someone advise what is required to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleMessageListenerContainer` can be used to start/stop listeners programatically.

```
simpleMessageListenerContainer.start("logical queue name")
```

Other than that you have two options. Using spring's `QueueMessagingTemplate`

```
Message<?> msg = ((QueueMessagingTemplate) template).receive("logical queue name");
```

this will requiere that no listeners are defined in the application for this queue.

Or use the spring cloud messaging annotation SQSListener

```
@SqsListener(value = "logical queue name")
```